# How do i work on my site whilst its 'A RECORD' is pointing to another DNS address?

Tags: magento, dns

How do I work on my site - say install and build my `Magento CE` version on domain www.myexampleshop.com , while it is actually pointing to a `Magento GO` site using a DNS `A Record` ?

Essentially I want my online store to point to the `Magento Go` version while I access my own `Magento CE` version on this same domain so I can work on it.

My problem is that the URL will always redirect to the `Magento Go` site. However, I want to install a `Magento CE` in the `cPanel` and work on it.

I have tried using redirects or IP exclusion but it won't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to develop locally on your own machine.